# Not getting paid overtime

Tags: overtime

I was told by my boss that I cannot work overtime, but then I got stuck there answering phones and taking care of a customer. So I did not get to clock out until 5:50.  My shift ends at 5:30. So since I was there 20 minutes over I was told that I have to leave 20 minutes early the next day, and not get overtime pay for that time.

I work for a retail mail order company.

Can an employer do this and not pay you for the time?

Comment: You are getting time off in lieu. So what is the problem?

Comment: What country? If in the US, are you exempt or non-exempt?

Comment: Depends on the country and local laws and the terms of your employment.

Comment: This is a legal question.

Comment: I've coded overtime calculations before.  The rules I was told to implement were based on the week, not the day.  Time over 40 hours in the week = overtime.  Period.  Obviously the rules can vary from place to place.

Comment: My (UK) contract only allows payment for overtime *if it's approved in advance* and then only if it lasts more than 30 minutes. Time off in lieu is the standard way of dealing with extra time outside those parameters. Your boss has a blanket ban on overtime, which you worked anyway: TOIL seems at least reasonable, if not more than reasonable.

Comment: You should tell us in which country you work. As other have commented, this varies from country to country. In my country any minute over 8h a day (7h if you work at night), or 40h a week must be paid as overtime, and is not allowed to "compensate" time like that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you are, and how many hours you had worked that day, or that week.

As a general rule, however, **yes, your employer can do this.**

Employers have a right to set your schedule so that it equals a certain number of hours in a week.

Employers often manage schedules to maximize part-time workers, minimize full-time workers, and as a result pay less toward employee health care and other benefits.